# Does Eilat-Ovda airport have ultra-high security like Ben Gurion airport?

Tags: airport-security, israel

I know that at Ben Gurion airport, security control can be a mess, with passengers being given a sticker with a number wherein one of the digits is 1-6 and determines how thoroughly you'll be searched/interrogated.

Does Eilat-Ovda airport have this as well, or otherwise particularly strict security?

Comment: I was strip searched at the Eilat and Ben Gurion airports both. Didn't try Ovda yet but I would be shocked if they didn't exercise similar caution.

Comment: I will test this on January 9 and report back if I don't forget it. My first Ryanair flight, eeeeeeek!

Comment: @chx Ryanair's not so bad. Then again I'm used to it (and Wizz)

Comment: @chk, I guess you've forgotten.

Comment: @ugoren No, he's stopped his activity due to a beef with the mods.

Comment: @Coke, A strip search didn't deter him, but the mods did... I also got name wrong.

Comment: Now doing this report is pointless because Ovda closes in six days.

Answer (score 3):

It's been years since I last flew through Ovda, but since nobody else has answered:

It's an Israeli airport, so yes, **security is quite strict**.  But instead of a TSA-style shoe parade where everybody gets subjected to the same idiocy unless they pay, the Israelis [profile ruthlessly](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/in-israel-racial-profiling-doesn-t-warrant-debate-or-apologies-1.5439830) and you'll be processed quite efficiently *if* you don't raise any flags (Arab/Muslim name/appearance, evidence of travel to Muslim countries or the Palestinian territories, etc).

Ovda is also a *much* smaller airport than Ben-Gurion, and it's scheduled to be closed down if/when [Ramon Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramon_International_Airport) opens (October 2018 at time of writing).